# haveibeenpwned.com usage with google user accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I've been asked to query haveibeenpwned.com on a daily basis for any new breaches involving our active list of user accounts in Google Workspace.  We have purchased the API for this use.

I am new to APIs but know they're basically interfaces between systems.  Presumably I need a platform and language to use the API with.  Does Google Cloud (which I know I can access) work for this purpose?  Has anyone done this?

I've successfully queried haveibeenowned by using their html link.  No idea how to automate this, specify our internal google accounts/time of breach, and parse the info, however.

Expect:
Daily email or report with any accounts from a list of active accounts that were involved in a breach reported by haveibeenpwned in the past day.

Comment: Yes, you can set it up with free Google Apps Script that would periodically pull the API and generate reports.  As an intermediary storage you can use Google Sheets.  You can also do it on Google Cloud but the setup will be more complex.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try Sheets and GApps Script.  Great idea!